# Wireless router with vpn server

Tags: vpn, router, wifi, wlan

I'm searching for a WLAN (Wifi) Router that can be used as VPN server as well for my home office. 
Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any [router](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) that can support dd-wrt would be useful. Then, follow the [instructions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/VPN) on the wiki to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

Try Bufflio router, around $40 and whole series has built in VPN server

http://www.buffalotech.com/products/wireless/routers-and-access-points/airstation-nfiniti-wireless-n-essential-high-power-router-access-point-whr-hp-g300n/

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Cisco/Linksys WRV210 with good success.  Setup is simple, allows multiple SSIDs and does RADIUS authentication. Also does QoS for our VoIP traffic.  Only 3-4 users right now.  Reasonably priced as well.

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9929/index.html

Answer (score -1):

you could use a PC Engines ALIX (http://www.pcengines.ch/alix.htm) or older version WRAP running pfSense free Firewall/Router solution (from pfSense dot org).
This is not too cheap, around 120 euros, but it very customizable and reliable.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer doesn't really help: it's very unspecific, linking to an OEM vendor page with only yet another link mentioning VPN at all.